# Spring data JPA with H2 database not returning non-merged data

Tags: spring, jpa, merge, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with created_date (updateable = false) and updated_date fields. I have @PreUpdate method where I change the updated_date value only (not change created_date), and @PrePersist method which sets new created_date and updated_date values. On Persist the created_date and updated_date are rightly persisted and the returned entity has the correct values. When I pass in the entity to merge, it rightly updates the updated_date (@PreUpdate), and I don't pass the created_date in input. In the database the right updated_date value is updated and created_date value is not changed rightly. But the returned entity has the created_date value set to null. Any Ideas why? Shouldn't the merged entity return the full entity loaded from the database?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is inline with the JPA [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-) javadoc.

Merge - *Merges the state of the given entity into the current persistence context and returns the managed instance that the state was merged to.*

- (With hibernate as persistence provider) Merge starts with loading the data from the database for that entity, then copies detached entities state to the newly loaded entity. Subsequently, at a later point, during the transaction commit phase(or flush) the dirty checking mechanism fires the update query but won't include the fields marked as `updatable=false`.
- So it doesn't attempt to reload the object with the data in the database after the UPDATE.

To trigger reload, you can rely on [refresh(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-) that will reload the data.

If it is `spring-data-jpa` it doesn't expose any `refresh` method, so you need to add it to your repository and and an example can be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/adding-entitymanagerrefresh-to-all-spring-data-rep) and discussion on this topic in the [spring forum here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/104364-entity-refresh-using-spring-data-jpa-module).

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response. I am using spring data JPA, hence I am not sure how to get the entity manager in this scenario. Is there any other way to get that while the entity is still attached (within the same transaction)? Thanks

Comment: @samuelpuppala Updated the answer for spring-data-jpa.